# Apache Beam write to BigQuery table and schema as params

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm using Python SDK for Apache Beam. The values of the datatable and the schema are in the PCollection. This is the message I read from the PubSub:

```
{"DEVICE":"rms005_m1","DATESTAMP":"2020-05-29 20:54:26.733 UTC","SINUMERIK__x_position":69.54199981689453,"SINUMERIK__y_position":104.31400299072266,"SINUMERIK__z_position":139.0850067138672}
```

Then I want to write it to BigQuery using the values in the json message with the lambda function for the datatable and this function for the schema:

```
def set_schema(data):
    list = []
    for name in data:
        if name == 'STATUS' or name == 'DEVICE':
            type = 'STRING'
        elif name == 'DATESTAMP':
            type = 'TIMESTAMP'
        else:
            type = 'FLOAT'
        list.append(name + ':' + type)
    schema = ",".join(list)
    return schema

data = (p
        | "Read from PubSub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic)
        | "Parse json" >> beam.Map(json_parse)
        | "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table='project:dataset{datatable}__opdata'.format(datatable = lambda element: element["DEVICE"]),
            schema=set_schema,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )
       )
```

When I execute it I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expected a table reference (PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE) instead of project:dataset.<function <lambda> at 0x7fa0dc378710>__opdata
```

How can I use the values of the PCollection as variables in the PTransform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a function into table. Try this, instead:

```
| "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=lambda element: 'project:dataset{datatable}__opdata'.format(datatable = element["DEVICE"]),
            schema=set_schema,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )
```